# Variation to balls and bins

Tags: probability, combinatorics, approximation, np-complete

I need some help in the following problem:

There are total $N$ balls where $n_1$ balls are of type 1, $n_1$ balls are of type 2 upto $n_p$ balls are of type $p$ i.e $n_1 + n_2 +...+n_p = N$.

Also, there are $M$ bins. A ball can be drawn independently out of $N$ balls and can be placed into any of the $M$ bins with uniform probability. Now, I have to find what is maximum number of distinct type of balls a bin can have with high probability. I am not sure how to solve this. Can this problem be mapped into any standard NP complete / approximation algo problem?

Comment: Is this the original question? I think it is very unclear. I don't think this relates to NP problems, but probably there is some reason for you to think it is. Can you provide some context of this problem?

Comment: Yes, it's the original question. I have updated the question to make it a bit clear.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. The "maximum number of distinct types of balls a bin can have" would be $p$, as there are $p$ types of balls. But I'm guessing this is not the intent of your question.

Comment: If you mean you are draw without replacement, and all placement of balls into bins are independent, then the number of $i$-th type balls in those bins  $(X_{i1}, X_{i2}, \ldots, X_{im})$ jointly follows $\text{Multinomial}(n; 1/m, 1/m, \ldots, 1/m)$. The number of distinct types in the $j$-th bin is the sum of indicator $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^p \mathbf{1}\{X_{ij} > 0\}$, and thus the maximum number of distinct types over all the bins is the random variable $\displaystyle \max_{j = 1, 2, \ldots m}\sum_{i=1}^p \mathbf{1}\{X_{ij} > 0\}$. And you want to know the distribution (pmf) of this?

Comment: Is it this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: No, it's not equivalent to bin packing. As I am not required to minimize the number of bins used. Only, thing is to find out maximum load a bin can have. It's similar to bins and balls problem. Only difference is the balls are not distinguishable and we have to find the maximum load of distinct balls a bin can have.

Comment: I suggest you make a simple example to clarify your question.